# Using Annotations and Pretty Printer

Tags: haskell

I'm using the pretty printer [Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.5.1/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html). Now I want to style my output differently and thought that the idea of semantic annotations fits well here. Consider the following example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc

data Foo = X | Y
data Ann = AnnX | AnnY

instance Pretty Foo where
  pretty X = "[" <+> (annotate AnnX "X was here") <+> "]"
  pretty Y = "nothing"
```

This fails with an error like

```
/Example.hs:14:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘ann’ with ‘Ann’
      ‘ann’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          pretty :: forall ann. Foo -> Doc ann
        at /Example.hs:14:3-8
      Expected type: Doc ann
        Actual type: Doc Ann
    • In the expression: "[" <+> (annotate AnnX "X was here") <+> "]"
      In an equation for ‘pretty’:
          pretty X = "[" <+> (annotate AnnX "X was here") <+> "]"
      In the instance declaration for ‘Pretty Foo’
    • Relevant bindings include
        pretty :: Foo -> Doc ann
          (bound at /Example.hs:14:3)
   |
14 |   pretty X = "[" <+> (annotate AnnX "X was here") <+> "]"
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which I barely understand. My intention was to annotate a document and later on I wanted to come up with different drivers for an annotation. For example, I wanted to have a driver which maps the document `X was here` to `<strong>X was here</strong>`  and another driver to `<i>X was here</i>`. Maybe I understood the whole annotation part wrongly. Can someone enlighten me or provide me a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

The `Pretty` typeclass requires things that can work with any type of annotation. In your case, they only work with your type `Ann`. Such a method would have to be its own thing, as it's not valid for `pretty`.

Comment: You are right, that is why it is `forall` quantified. Any idea how annotation is supposed to be used? I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: @MaxMaier Create a method with some other name, and use it in place of `pretty`.